# Connect to a smtp server through docker

Tags: python, docker, smtp, containers, smtplib

I've created a python app and I'm using **smtplib** to connect to a smtp server. My code works well outside of docker but when I try to launch it inside of my **docker** container I get the following error:

```
[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# ADD PORT
EXPOSE 25

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "get_data.py"]
```

and my smtp connexion function:

```
def setupSMTPserver():
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port="25")
        server.starttls()
        server.login("eran.idar@gmail.com", "E.419762")

        return server
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Then I get the **[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address error**. And server is undefined

I added EXPOSE 25 in my dockerfile, but I'm sure the issue doesn't come from this.

If someone has the solution or an idea where to look at.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your code does not explain the error. Please provide all information required to reproduce this.